# "whereby agencies avoid dramatic declarations on the chance they might be wrong"

Tags: sentence-structure

> Straitford's briefs don't sound like the usual Washington back-and forthing, whereby agencies avoid dramatic declarations on the chance they might be wrong.

I understand the meaning of the sentence, but its attributive clause "whereby agencies avoid dramatic declarations on the chance they might be wrong" is so hard.

How to analyze its structure?

I know "Whereby agencies avoid dramatic declarations on the chance they might be wrong" is a (non-defining) relative clause. But the "they might be wrong" is a relative clause to modify "on the chance"? How to understand the relationship among dramatic declarations on the chance and they might be wrong?

Comment: This question was answered a few years ago, but I'll just add that "whereby" is equivalent here (and in general) to "by which".

Comment: which is the way that agencies etc.

Answer (score 1):

> *Straitford's briefs don't sound like the usual Washington back-and*
>   *forthing,* [*whereby agencies avoid dramatic declarations on the chance*
>   [*they might be wrong*]].

The element in the outer brackets is a supplementary (non-defining) relative clause in which "whereby" is the relativised element with the NP "the usual "Washington back-and-forthing" as its semantic 'anchor'/ antecedent.

The element in in the inner brackets is a declarative content clause functioning as complement of "chance".

Comment: @kun ahu There is no relativized element (overt or understood) in "they might be wrong" so it can't be a relative clause The clause functions as complement of "chance".

Comment: Why "they might be wrong" has no 'anchor'/ antecedent?

Comment: Is its antecedent omitted?

Comment: No, there is no antecedent because it is not a relative clause. Content clause are not the same as relative clauses, in that they act as complement to some expression, not as modifier to a nominal (the antecedent).

Comment: If add a 'that' before "they might be wrong". Is it right or not?

Comment: You can add "that" -- it is optional. But it doesn't change the analysis. "(That) they might be wrong" is still a content clause.

Comment: My English teacher tell me that content clause must have a 'anchor'/ antecedent. This is the reason why I am confused.

Comment: Sorry, but your English teacher is wrong. Content clauses functioning as complement, like the one in your example, do not have an anchor/antecedent.

Comment: Thank you very much.